# How to hide an action button in Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, iboutlet, ibaction

I try to make a button invisible after pressing it. The Connection is an action and not an outlet, because pressing the button will call additional code.

```
@IBAction func startGame(_ sender: Any) {
    print("The game starts...")

}
```

This does not work, because the button is an action and not an outlet:

```
startGame.isHidden = true
```

Is there another way to make an action button invisible and therefore not clickable?

Comment: try `sender.isHidden = true`

Comment: What is an _action button_, technically?

Comment: @PratikPrajapati sender.isHidden = true unfortunately does not work either

Comment: change `_ sender: Any` to `_ sender: UIButton` n try again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create an `IBOutlet` of the same button and set its `isHidden` property to `true` once it's tapped.

```
@IBAction func startGame(_ sender: Any) {
     startGameButton.isHidden = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide button on pressed action this way

```
 @IBAction func startGame(_ sender: Any) {
    let pressedButton : UIButton = sender as! UIButton
    pressedButton.isHidden = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite your code a little bit as Pratik suggested, so it will look like this:

```
@IBAction func startGame(_ sender: UIButton) {
    sender.isHidden = true
    /*
    remove button at all from the parent view.
    sender.removeFromSuperview()
    */
    print("The game starts...")
}
```